# AWS Lambda POST Request from event ObjectCreated S3 bucket (Node.js)

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I am new to Lambda and the S3 bucket so bear with me.

I have set up an AWS SES that sends emails to an S3 bucket which works great. What I am trying to do now is when the event `ObjectCreated` is fired when the S3 bucket receives a new object that I trigger a `Lambda` function (node.js) to `POST` to a URL on my server that gets the filename which then will allow me to download that particular object and process the email.

Here is a breakdown

- User sends email
- Email is created as an object in an S3 bucket
- Lambda function (node.js) is fired from the `ObjectCreated` event
- Lambda sends `POST` to a script on my server sending me the filename
- My script downloads the object from the S3 bucket
- All Done!

The problem is that the `POST` is never happening. Any help to guide me?

What I am trying to avoid is creating a cron job that checks my bucket every minute to see if there are new emails(objects) and process them that way. What I want to do it every time a new object comes into the bucket I can trigger the script and send the object name so that I can then just grab that particular object and process it immediately.

**SES rule**

[image]

**Lambda**

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var https = require('https');
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        'fileName': event.Records[0].s3.object.key,
    });

    var options = {
        host: 'example.com',
        port: '80',
        path: '/path/script/this_script.php',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'Content-Length': data.length
        }
    };

    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
        var msg = '';

        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            msg += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            console.log(JSON.parse(msg));
            context.succeed();
        });
    });

    req.write(data);
    req.end();
};
```

Also no matter what I do when I test Lambda I always get this error

```
{
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "Cannot read property '0' of undefined",
  "trace": [
    "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined",
    "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:5:34)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You mean lambda is not getting triggered or it is getting triggered but post is not happening?

Comment: Lambda is being triggered but not posting